# Trying to get a prompt to limit the first three character of a prompt to letters only

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement, do-while, prompt

So i have this code that i want to be able to limit what can be said in a prompt box using javascript. I am using a do and while statement to push out a prompt loop until the prompt meets the requirement, i am only allowed to use javascript. I want the first three characters of the prompt box to be only letters, however i think i have a problem with my regex! any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   function myFunction() {
  var userInput = new Array();
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  do {
     userInput = prompt('Enter course code');
     if (userInput.length != 7) {
        alert("The input must contain 7 characters");
     }
     var userInput3 = userInput.substring(0, 3);
     if (userInput3 != /[A-Za-z]+$/){
        alert("The first 3 characters must be letters");
     }
  }
  while (userInput.length != 7 && userInput3 != /[A-Za-z]+$/){
  }

}
```

Comment: Please don't, that's incredible awful way to ask information.

Answer (score 1):

You just compare first 3 letter with string '/[A-Za-z]+$/'

Try this

```js
function myFunction() {
  var userInput = new Array();
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  do {
     userInput = prompt('Enter course code');
     if (userInput.length != 7) {
        alert("The input must contain 7 characters");
     }
     var userInput3 = userInput.substring(0, 3);
     if (!/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z].*/.exec(userInput3)){
        alert("The first 3 characters must be letters");
     }
  }
  while (userInput.length != 7 && userInput3 != /[A-Za-z]+$/){
  }

}

myFunction()
```

Comment: Just to add an alternative for `/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z].*/`, which is `/^[A-Za-z]{3}.*/` use `{3}` to specify the quantity of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Using this regex `^[a-zA-Z]{3}.{4}$` you can achieve it in single if loop,

```js
function myFunction() {
  var userInput = new Array();
  do {
     userInput = prompt('Enter course code');
     if (!/^[a-zA-Z]{3}.{4}$/.test(userInput)) {
        alert("The input must contain 7 characters where first 3 characters must be letters");
     }
  }
  while (!/^[a-zA-Z]{3}.{4}$/.test(userInput)){
  }

}

myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression you're feeling your way through this at the moment, theres a lot you could do to make your code safer and more efficient in general. while loops are a dangerous way to kill time for a start.

In terms of your regexp problem, try using .test if you're looking for a boolean (true or false) response to your regexp test

For example

`/([A-Z]|[a-z])/.test(userInput3)`

will return true if all the characters are letters between a to z in lower or upper case ( | is or ).

if you add ! before the test you will reverse its boolean value (true becomes false and vice verse)

so you could go:

```
if (!/([A-Z]|[a-z])/.test(userInput3)){
/* do something if userInput3 contains anything other than the letters a-z in 
   upper or lower case */
}
```

so

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code.

```
function myFunction() {
  var userInput;
  //var regEx = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]{3}.{4}$"); // It Will check for first 3 must be characters and length 7
  var regEx = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]{3}"); // It Will check for first 3 must be characters and not check for length
  do {
     userInput = prompt('Enter course code');
     if (userInput.length != 7) {
        alert("The input must contain 7 characters");
     }
     if (!regEx.test(userInput)){
        alert("The first 3 characters must be letters");
     }
  }
  while (userInput.length != 7 && regEx.test(userInput)){
  }

}
```